# Mojolicious - return flow dependent on values

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How would I go about if the value isn't a number (as in the `host_id` is invalid)? At present it just returns the `not_found` page instead of executing the `get_host_id` function.

The ideal behaviour of the function is that, if it receives a number it will execute the first part of the if statement but if it is say a string it will return the `not_found` page.

```
sub get_host_id {
    my $self = shift;
    my $host_id = $self->stash('host_id');

    if ( $RE{num}{int}->matches($host_id) ) {
        my $hostid = $host_id = $self->hosts->get_host_id($host_id);
        return $self;
    }
    else{
        return $self->redirect_to('/not_found');
    }
```